# Divergent to $\infty \Rightarrow$ Divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinity

In our lecture, we defined a sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ to be divergent if it does not converge, and additionally to be divergent to $\pm \infty$, iff:
$$\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb R: \exists N \in \mathbb N: \forall n > N: \pm a_n\ge \pm\epsilon$$

But I do not see how that could imply the negation of the convergence definition:
$$
\neg\exists a \in \mathbb R:\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists N \in \mathbb N: \forall n \ge N: \left|a_n-a\right|<\epsilon\\
\Leftrightarrow \forall a \in \mathbb R:\exists \epsilon > 0: \forall N \in \mathbb N: \exists n \ge N: \left|a_n-a\right|>\epsilon
$$

$\dots$Mainly because I just do not see how one an switch the last 2 Quantors.

How can one (elegantly) prove this implication?

Comment: Divergent to $\infty\implies$ Divergent, but Divergent $\not\implies$ Divergent to $\infty$.

Comment: $a_n = (-1)^n$ is divergent, but not divergent to $\pm \infty$.

Comment: @John: That does not contradict the title of the question.

Comment: But that answers the question the OP posted, divergence to $\pm \infty$ cannot be implied by negation of convergence. @barakmanos

Comment: I did not ask for the implication divergent $\Rightarrow$ divergent to $\infty$, I asked for the other direction. It is quite obvious that being divergent in terms of not being convergent is the "broader" statement here.
The intuition is not the problem here, rather is the proof.

Comment: @LukasJuhrich: Now I am confused: You said "I do not see how that (divergent at $\pm \infty$) could be implied by the negation of the convergence (divergnece) definition" ??

Comment: I am sorry, that was a mistake. I meant the opposite.

Comment: @Ruslan: Thanks for the LaTex advice :)

Comment: @barakmanos sorry, it appeared to not work for MathJax, so I removed it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $$\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb R: \exists N \in \mathbb N: \forall n > N: \pm a_n\ge \pm\epsilon$$
which you will agree implies that
$$\forall a \in \mathbb R: \exists N \in \mathbb N: \forall n > N: |a_n|\ge |a|+1\tag{$\ast$}$$
one is asked to show that
$$\forall a \in \mathbb R:\exists \epsilon > 0: \forall N \in \mathbb N: \exists n \ge N: \left|a_n-a\right|>\epsilon\tag{$\circ$}
$$
Well, I say that, by the triangular inequality, $\left|a_n-a\right|\geqslant|a_n|-|a|$ hence $(\ast)$ implies
$$\forall a \in \mathbb R: \forall N \in \mathbb N: \exists n \ge N: \left|a_n-a\right|>1\tag{$\dagger$}
$$
hence $(\circ)$ holds for $\epsilon=1$. Surely you can prove that $(\ast)$ implies $(\dagger)$?

Answer (score 0):

I think I can give a proof of divergence at $ \infty \Rightarrow $ divergence: (THe other case $-\infty$ is similar.

Assume that $(a_n)$ diverges to $+\infty$. Then let $a\in \mathbb R$. Let $\epsilon = a+1 \in \mathbb R$. Then by definition there is $K\in \mathbb N$ so that $a_n \geq a+1$ for all $N\in \mathbb K$. In particular, for all $N\in \mathbb N$, there is $n\geq N$ so that

$$ a_n \geq a+1 \Rightarrow |a_n  - a| \geq 1$$

So if we let $\epsilon_0 = 1/2$, then

$$\forall a\in \mathbb R, \exists \epsilon_0 = 1/2 >0, \forall N\in \mathbb N, \exists n \geq N, |a_n - a| \geq \epsilon_0.$$

Thus $(a_n)$ is divergence. Actually your negation is correct.